# Error 26 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I get the following error **Error   26  Cannot implicitly convert type
'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
cast?)** ON THIS LINE string str = rd[0].ToString(); when try to get filepath in string can anyone sort out my
problem

thanks in advance

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        String query = "select [PDFFilePath] from [dbo].[AdmPDFManage] Where [PdfId] = (SELECT MAX([PdfId]) FROM [dbo].[AdmPDFManage]) ";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = new SqlDataReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            string str = rd[0].ToString();

        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

> I ALSO TRY THIS BUT GET THE SAME ERROR

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                String query = "select [PDFFilePath] from [dbo].[AdmPDFManage] Where [PdfId] = (SELECT MAX([PdfId]) FROM [dbo].[AdmPDFManage]) ";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                con.Open();

                String PDFfilePath = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();              

            }
```

Comment: On which line exactly? What is the value of `rd[0]` exactly? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: your code doesn't show any object-to-string assignments... can you clarify which line is flagging this error? Also: that exception handling is redundant and should be removed

Comment: @Trafz no, that is bad advice; the `using` deals with that; it is pointless to add an extra `try`/`finally` to `Close()` - and introduces more places to make mistakes. Do not do that. `using` is fine.

Comment: Oh. Bad advice removed. I still use try-catch-finally instead of using because I was unsure if it actually closed it. Guess I shouldn't anymore.

Comment: how did this line even compiled SqlDataReader rd = new SqlDataReader()? shouldn't it be SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader()?

Comment: Re the edit; the line `sting str = rd[0].ToString();` - that returns a `string`, not an `object` - that cannot produce the error you report

Comment: IS THEIR ANY OTHER WAY BY WHICH I GET FILEPATH NAME IN STRING THEN SUGGEST ME

Comment: "I ALSO TRY THIS BUT GET THE SAME ERROR" - no, again, that is impossible, because *that does not do what the error says*.

Comment: Specifically, the error that the code in the question outputs is: "'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue; it should work fine. There are, however, 2 problems:

- creating the `SqlDataReader` incorrectly
- not using the `.ConnectionString` from the configuration item

The following compiles fine:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    const string query = "select [PDFFilePath] from [dbo].[AdmPDFManage] Where [PdfId] = (SELECT MAX([PdfId]) FROM [dbo].[AdmPDFManage]) ";
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    con.Open();
    using(var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            string str = rd[0].ToString();
            // .. do something
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you only expect 1 row, `ExecuteScalar` is simpler:

```
cmd.CommandText = query;
con.Open();
string str = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```